# How do I stop using ssh-agent?

Tags: ssh, ssh-agent

I use my keys without any password because all machines involved operate in a fairly closed environment. So I do not need ssh-agent. But I accidentally ran a script that seems to have enabled it use, and I cannot get it to stop.

I can kill the process, but upon next boot, since the 'decrypted' key isn't in the cache, I am not able to ssh without the error message:

```
sign_and_send_pubkey: signing failed: agent refused operation
```

The 'culprit' seems to be `$SSH_AUTH_SOCK`. Will all of this be solved if I just remove that? Or is there a better way?

**EDIT**: The `$SSH_AUTH_SOCK` variable only exists when I check from a terminal in my GNOME desktop. If I check from a tty, it returns nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that Gnome is the actual culprit here. Or more precisely the gnome keyring.
Have you tried the method **[suggested here](http://dtek.net/2012/09/19/how-stop-gnome-keyring-clobbering-opensshs-ssh-agent-ubuntu-1204.html)** to disable ssh in the gnome keyring? The link concerns the gnome keyring under Ubuntu, but the information seems fairly distro-agnostic.

The **[Arch Linux wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/GNOME/Keyring#SSH_keys)** also has a good description of this:

> Disable keyring daemon components
>
> If you wish to run an alternative SSH agent (e.g. ssh-agent or gpg-agent, you need to **disable the ssh component of GNOME Keyring**. To do so in an account-local way:

```
#!/bin/sh

mkdir ~/.config/autostart
cp /etc/xdg/autostart/gnome-keyring-ssh.desktop ~/.config/autostart/ &&
printf '%s\n' 'Hidden=true' >> ~/.config/autostart/gnome-keyring-ssh.desktop
```